# position: absolute;した親要素の高さがなくなるのを解消する一般的な(clearfixのような)方法はありませんか？

Tags: html, css

```
.box {position: absolute;}
```

とした要素の親要素の高さ（幅も？）がなくなるのを解消する
一般的な(clearfixのような)方法はありませんか？

[html]

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="box_left">
        A
      </div>
      <div class="box_right">
        B
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

[css]

before---------------------------------------------

```
  *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .wrap{
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px;
  }

  .box_left{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: tomato;
    /*position: absolute;*/
  }

  .box_right{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: lime;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    right:0;
  }
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

after---------------------------------------------

```
.box {position: absolute;}
```

すると、

.wrap（グレー）の高さ（幅も？）がなくなる！
↓↓↓

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .wrap{
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px;
  }


  .box_left{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: tomato;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .box_right{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: lime;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
  }
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
↑↑↑↑↑↑
.wrap（グレー）の高さ（幅も？）がなくなる！

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ないです。

`position: absolute` や `position: fixed` が指定された要素は、通常のレイアウト処理から除外されるため、**あたかも要素が存在していないかのように**後続要素や親要素がレイアウトされます。float 等とは異なり、親要素の枠の外にでも配置できますから、その高さを親要素に考慮させるというのは無理な話です。

要素を横に並べる用途で使いたい場合、親要素に height を指定したり、`position: absolute` ではない要素も残すなどして、別途高さを確保しなければいけません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！勉強になりました！ちなみに親要素は、高さがなくなっても子要素の配置の基準になるようですね。